# [FireDac][Phys][MySql]using unsupported buffer type: 253 (parameter:2)

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

I'm trying to switch from ADO to FireDac for my apps. I connected to my MySQL via FDConnection, whene I set FDTable.Active to true, I have the following error:

```
[FireDac][Phys][MySql]using unsupported buffer type: 253 (parameter:2)
```

I tried to connect to several MySQL servers  on Windows and Ubuntu but I still have the same error. 
please any suggestions to solve this problem??.

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using? The mentioned error supposed to be fixed in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo Release 1. Check RSP-17817 entry at [List of new features and customer reported issues fixed in RAD Studio 10.2 Tokyo Release 1](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/44763)

Comment: You can get a bit more info on why this error is happening from [MySQL Blogs](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74273) even thou the thread is descirbing smae error happening in C++ and not Delphi. Maybe this Will help you solve your problem without upgrading to newer version of Delphi if that isn't feasable to you for some reason.

Comment: SilverWarior, i have delphi 10.2 tokyo !!

Comment: FYI: using ADO compenents works fine

Comment: You have Delphi 10.2 Tokyo but this bug was fixed with first update for Delphi 10.2 Tokyo. Therefore if you have Active Update subscription or had Active update subscription at the time you should update to newest Update available for Delphi 10.2 Tokyo [10.2 Tokyo - Release 3](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/10.2_Tokyo_-_Release_3)